# Company share with file attachment through API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I've been told it's possible to make company shares with file attachments, but I can't find anything about it in the documentation. In the Apigee console, I see a file attachment field in the body section, but I get a `400 Bad Request` error when I try it. So is this really possible? Or is it only with the partners program?